# Login user account on server side

Tags: meteor

Let say I have a method called `connectServer` on the server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
   connectServer: function(data) {
         <check if connection has valid data.accessToken from RESTful end point>
         if (valid) {
              var userId = Accounts.createUser({"email": data.email});
              this.setUserId(userId);
         }
   }
});
```

The problem with this method is that it doesn't seem to trigger any 'login connection' actions on server. I'm currently using `meteor-user-status` and the event `UserStatus.events.on("connectionLogin", function(fields) { ... })` is not called when `this.setUserId(userId)` has updated. Is there any way I can manually trigger a 'login connection' action on server? Thanks.

Note: I'm not using Meteor's client, so I would like to do this on the server side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status/blob/master/status.coffee#L133-L139), you could emit a `connectionLogin` event:

```js
UserStatus.events.emit("connectionLogin", {
    userId: userId
    connectionId: connection.id
    ipAddr: connection.clientAddress
    userAgent: connection.httpHeaders['user-agent']
    loginTime: date
});
```

Seems like an OK thing to do, but bear in mind that if the package is updated and something changes, your code might break without you even noticing.

The next place to stick your finger into would be the `Accounts` package (since `meteor-user-status` uses the `Accounts.onLogin()` method), however I looked into it and couldn't find an easy way to do that.

Your last option is to log the user in client-side. What you could do is generate a token and allow the client to log in with this token. E.g:

```js
// Server method
Meteor.methods({
   connectServer: function(data) {
         <check if connection has valid acess token>
         if (valid) {
              var userId = Accounts.createUser({"email": data.email});
              var stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
              Accounts._insertLoginToken(userId, stampedLoginToken);
              return stampedLoginToken;
         }
   }
});
// Client
Meteor.call('connectServer', function(error, result){
    if(!error) Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token);
});
```

Comment: The first solution works! I'll take a deeper look at your suggested third solution. Thanks!

Comment: For the last option, what if I'm not using Meteor's Client? How can I call `Meteor.loginWithToken` on a third-party DDP client? (Note: I'm using https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios for client side)

Answer (score 2):

Simple process to authenticate user on server

find the user if exist from parameter email

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
  'emails.address': data.email
  });
```

if the user is found

```
if (user) {
  //get paramter password
  var password = data.password;
  //authenticate user
  var result = Accounts._checkPassword(user, password);
```

Client call method

```
Meteor.call('loginUser', {email: "vxxxxx@xxxx.com", password: "123456"}, function (error, result) {
  if (!error) Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token);
});
```

Full code

```
// Server method
Meteor.methods({
  loginUser: function (data) {
    //find user if exist from paramter email
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
      'emails.address': data.email
    });

    //if user is found
    if (user) {
      //get paramter password
      var password = data.password;
      //authenticate user
      var result = Accounts._checkPassword(user, password);
      if (result.error) {
        return result.error;
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    } else {
      //if user is not found
      return {
        error: "user not found"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Client call method

```
 Meteor.call('loginUser', {email: "vxxxxx@xxxx.com", password: "123456"}, function (error, result) {
      if (!error) Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token);
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer would be better if you could add some explanation to your code.

Comment: why is there not a blog article regarding this!?! % hours, yes 5 hours I have spent looking for this solution. I have tried salting the pass the way meteor does but they have their own sha implementation and all kinds of other garbage. Thank you for this. I dont know how i missed the _checkPassword method as i had scanned over that file 50 times.

Comment: `_checkPassword` does not seem to return a token

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a callback to `createUser` and tell us what happens? I'm not sure if that will fix it but I'm pretty sure you need to set a password too, such as:

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password
  }, function(err, res){
    console.log(err, res);
  }
});
```

Otherwise I did not see your `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId, [email])` if you want to let users choose their passwords.

Comment: Can't add a callback on server to `createUser`: Exception while invoking method 'connectChatServer' Error: Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet.

Comment: My Accounts collection doesn't required a password, so I don't think Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId, [email]) is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code where I've also added the token issuing logic. Previous answer is not sufficient if you don't want to use a Meteor method (login through an HTTP call or a GraphQL call for example) because it won't generate the auth `token`. 
It probably worked for older versions (as we use Meteor hidden functions, expect breaking change) or maybe if you use a Meteor method but not in my case. My code is tested on Meteor 1.8.3.

```
 // Suppose that userSelector = {username:"foobar"} or {email:"whatever@stackoverflow.com}
const user = Accounts._findUserByQuery(userSelector);
 // TODO check that your user is valid (not null, have password...

const passwordCheck = Accounts._checkPassword(
  user,
  options.password
);
// TODO check that passwordCheck is valid

const stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
Accounts._insertLoginToken(userId, stampedLoginToken);
return {
  userId,
  token: stampedLoginToken.token
};
```

**NOTE: This is not a secured version! I just wanted to demonstrate the logic. You also need to check every intermediate result, and if possible reintroduce Meteor accounts "_attemptLogin" logic.**