# Meteor - initiate client login automatically

Tags: meteor, nginx

i have a meteor app where i'm using nginx with an internal SSO service to authenticate.  I'm able to do this successfully and retrieve user details in the nginx set http headers on the server Meteor.onConnection method.

At this point, i'm not sure what the best approach is to get access to the user details on the client side.  I feel like i should use the built in Meteor Accounts but i'm not sure how to initiate the login process from the client since the user will not actually be logging in through the Meteor client but through a redirect that happens through nginx.  I feel like i need a way to automatically initiate the login process on the meteor side to set up the meteor.users collection appropriately, but i can't figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085553/login-user-account-on-server-side). You can pass the userId (or in whatever you want to pass the user) through nginx to the server then onto the client to login. You can generate and insert the token in a Webapp.connectHandler.

```
import { Inject } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:inject-initial';
// server/main.js
Meteor.startup(() => {
    WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/login",function(req, res, next) {
      Fiber(function() {
        var userId = req.headers["user-id"]
        if (userId){
           var stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
           //check if user exists
           Accounts._insertLoginToken(userId, stampedLoginToken);
           Inject.obj('auth', {
             'loginToken':stampedLoginToken
           },res);             
           return next() 
        }
      }).run()
    })       
}
```

Now you can login on the client side with the help of the [meteor-inject-initial package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-inject-initial)

```
import { Inject } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:inject-initial';
// iron router
Router.route('/login', {
    action: function() {
        if (!Meteor.userId()){
            Meteor.loginWithToken(Inject.getObj('auth').loginToken.token, 
                function(err,res){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
            )
        } else {
            Router.go('/home')
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: where would i add the Client code so that it fires when a new user hits the app?

Comment: You can do it in client/main.js in `Meteor.startup(...)` or in a `if (Meteor.isClient()){...}` in a imported shared file like lib/router.js or the `waitOn` of `Router.config` if you are using Iron Router...

Comment: you could also do in the `waitOn` or `action` of the '/login' route if you have that because that's the route that's being called in my example (if you are using Iron Router)

Comment: The server side looks good except for setting the header.  When i do a headers.get() on the client, i don't see the header i set on the server.  I didn't even set a key to filter on, i just did a headers.get()

Comment: so it worked with `headers.get()['loginToken']` to update my answer?

Comment: no, i can't get it to work on the client with anything.  I'm dumping everything from headers.get() to console log to see what's in there and i don't see 'loginToken'.  If i console.log(res) from the server i see _headers: { loginToken: 'foo' },

Comment: i created a gist with my client and server main.js files.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/151b27894ef4754140091d0d4d9de188

Comment: i just noticed that in chrome i can see the header populated in the Response Headers.  However, it seems that the meteor headers module only allows access to the request headers.  I can't figure out how to get access to the response headers now.

Comment: my bad. you can remove the headers package and use the inject package it's built on. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This now works.  I hate to keep throwing questions at you but I now see that my user has many loginTokens under services.resume.loginTokens in the users collection.  Does that need to be cleaned up manually?

Comment: awesome, I am glad. set it the correct answer then, the loginTokens expire after a certain time (which you can configure).

Comment: so.. the code as it is generates a logintoken every time a user goes into /login. Instead, you can check the request cookie for a userId and a loginToken (that you insert into the cookie on the client) to make sure user is not logged in already.

Comment: Here's the gist of how to you can do this to get you started. https://gist.github.com/mutdmour/2775171728315f5835dde6e208afbc44

Comment: @MikeSmith, any updates? Let me remind you to accept the answer and/or upvote the answer if it helped you so that others with the same question in the future will see that the answer helped you and follow the same advice.

Comment: this is working great.  Unfortunately i'm a new users here and don't have enough reputation points to accept your answer.  As soon as i do , i will mark it appropriately.  Thank you again for all of your help.