# Electron user authentication with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, electron, meteor-accounts

How would I authenticate users logging in from an Electron desktop application?

Meteor comes with a default user system. If I was authenticating from the client of a Meteor app, I could do something like the following to login:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(err) {
    if (err == null) {
        //success
        console.log('success!');                
    } else {
        //error
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

What's the best way to authenticate users in an Electron app?

Comment: [this might help with the meteor side of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669482/meteor-initiate-client-login-automatically/42672312#42672312)

Comment: @mutdmour I'm not sure I follow. The electron app does not use meteor itself whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry. Just learning about electron and looking  at [a project that uses both](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/develop/README.md)