# Log in from headers (X-Forwarded-User)

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I develop some internal applications for a client startup. All internal applications go through a reverse proxy, that verifies an OAuth login and lets the proxied webapp know of the user with a header value (X-Forwarded-User).

I would like to have users be logged in to the Meteor app when this header is sent, and to create the user if it does not exist.

Can't seem to find any good info on this use case online.

Where to start?

Would an ideal solution be to create a package for this (eg. accounts-from-headers)?
If so, would this be a common enough use case to make it public?

Comment: [Checkout my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669482/meteor-initiate-client-login-automatically/42672312#42672312). Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor - initiate client login automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669482/meteor-initiate-client-login-automatically)